# В всплывающем окне скрипт срабатывает со 2 клика

Tags: javascript, php

Уже голова не варит куда копать, помогайте комрады!

Ссылка на кнопке -

```
<div class="btn btn--wide" onclick="javascript:square2()" id="goc">Подай заявку сейчас!</div>
```

Сам скрипт -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function square2() {
 jQuery( "#goc" ).click(function() {
    var g1 = jQuery('#output1').text();
    var g2 = jQuery('#output2').text();
    var g3 = 'https://lk.zaimdam.ru/?creditproduct=%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2&amount='+ g1 +'&period='+ g2;
    location.href = g3;
  });
  }</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery( "#goc" ).click(function() {
    var g1 = jQuery('#output1').text();
    var g2 = jQuery('#output2').text();
    var g3 = 'https://lk.zaimdam.ru/?creditproduct=%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2&amount='+ g1 +'&period='+ g2;
    location.href = g3;
  });

window.onload = function(){

var output1 = document.getElementById("output1");
var output2 = document.getElementById("output2");
var output3 = document.getElementById("output3");

   setTimeout(function() {
    output3.innerHTML =(output1.innerHTML*1)+(output1.innerHTML/100)*output2.innerHTML+" р." ;
    }, 8);

jQuery("#output1").on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
   output3.style.opacity = 0;
   setTimeout(function() {
    output3.innerHTML =(output1.innerHTML*1)+(output1.innerHTML/100)*output2.innerHTML+" р." ;
    output3.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 8);
});

jQuery("#output2").on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  output3.style.opacity = 0;
   setTimeout(function() {
    output3.innerHTML =(output1.innerHTML*1)+(output1.innerHTML/100)*output2.innerHTML+" р." ;
    output3.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 8);
});
};
 </script>
```

Работает только через двойной клик и ни как больше...

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код использует два способа задать действие при щелчке:

- через `jQuery.click(...)`
- через `onclick="javascript:square2()"`

В обоих способах есть баги. Нужно оставить только какой-то один, и исправить баги.

Обычно рекомендуют использовать первый способ.

---

**Первый способ** скорее всего не срабатывает из-за того, что ваш код из второго тега `script` расположен выше, чем `div#goc`. На момент вызова этого кода `div#goc` ещё не существует (браузер ещё не дошёл до него и не создал этот элемент), поэтому `jQuery( "#goc" ).click(...)` уходит в пустоту.

Проблему можно решить, отложив выполнение кода до тех пор, пока все элементы на странице не будут готовы. В jQuery для этого есть функция `jQuery(document).ready(function () {...})`. Эта функция используется так часто, что для неё есть сокращённая запись — `jQuery(function () {...})`

То есть вот этот код из второго скрипта:

```
jQuery( "#goc" ).click(function() {
  var g1 = jQuery('#output1').text();
  var g2 = jQuery('#output2').text();
  var g3 = 'https://lk.zaimdam.ru/?creditproduct=%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2&amount='+ g1 +'&period='+ g2;
  location.href = g3;
});
```

можно преобразовать таким образом:

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery( "#goc" ).click(function() {
    var g1 = jQuery('#output1').text();
    var g2 = jQuery('#output2').text();
    var g3 = 'https://lk.zaimdam.ru/?creditproduct=%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2&amount='+ g1 +'&period='+ g2;
    location.href = g3;
  });
});
```

---

**Второй способ** не работает потому, что внутри функции `square2` не происходит самого действия. Первый щелчок задаёт поведение при щелчках (следующих щелчках!), а больше ничего не делает. Вот и получается, что функция работает только при втором щелчке.

Чтобы функция работала, просто поместите код напрямую, а не внутри `jQuery( "#goc" ).click(function() {...})`.

То есть вместо такого:

```js
function square2() {
 jQuery( "#goc" ).click(function() {
    var g1 = jQuery('#output1').text();
    var g2 = jQuery('#output2').text();
    var g3 = 'https://lk.zaimdam.ru/?creditproduct=%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2&amount='+ g1 +'&period='+ g2;
    location.href = g3;
  });
}
```

Используйте такое:

```js
function square2() {
  var g1 = jQuery('#output1').text();
  var g2 = jQuery('#output2').text();
  var g3 = 'https://lk.zaimdam.ru/?creditproduct=%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2&amount='+ g1 +'&period='+ g2;
  location.href = g3;
}
```